# Update className attribute

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For the avatarColor I am selecting a random color AKA -> rendomColor.

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    let colorArr = [classes.redAvatar, classes.greenAvatar, classes.blueAvatar, classes.redAvatar];

    const usersListedItems = this.state.ownersArr.map((owner, index) => {
        return (
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} key={owner.ownerId}>
                <UsersListedItems
                    ownerId={owner.ownerId}
                    userName={owner.userName}
                    avatarColor={colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)]}>
                </UsersListedItems>
            </Grid>
        )
```

How can I update (in UsersListedItems component) the card style borderColor with the same random color that I calculated for the avatar?

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
},
card: {
    borderRadius: '14px',
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: ????? 
},

  });

   ........

return (
        <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                    <Avatar id="av" aria-label="Recipe" className={this.props.avatarColor}>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other ways, but at least you can do it through styles specifically:

```
        <Card 
        className={classes.card}
        style={{
            borderColor: this.props.avatarColor
        }} >
        <CardHeader
            avatar={
                <Avatar id="av" aria-label="Recipe" className={this.props.avatarColor}>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but its not working. Looks like it will work only if the borderColor will be part of the classes.card

Comment: Inline styling should at least work with material UI; https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#inline-style. If you have a code pen or similar I could look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the link it help me to understand your solution.     <Card style={{
                ...styles.card, ...(this.props.avatarColor !== null ? { borderColor: this.calcCardBorderColor() } : { borderColor: 'aliceblue' })
            }}>

Comment: calcCardBorderColor = () => {
        let element = document.getElementById(this.props.ownerId);
        if (element) {
            let elementComputedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);
            return elementComputedStyle['backgroundColor'];
        }
    }